# E: The package jdk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 14.04, apt, jdk

any one help me please 
i can't use apt-get anymore and I searched about this problem and all solutions have failed

[image: this is the error message]

[image: this is the error message]

i removed jdk and installed it but the problem still exists