# how to reinstall libsnpav0/libspnav0

Tags: package-management, updates

E:The package libspnav0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

and no one working: not Ubuntu Software Centre, nor Synaptic. I tried to use apt-get - the same:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnpav0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libspnav0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

BUT!!!
see carefully, please! my typed request - about lib**snp**av0, but system answer - about lib**spn**av0.  and if I shange this letter in request - the answer not changing... just mistery...

AND there is no one trace of this lib in the
/var/lib/dpkg/status

so, how to install this lib?

thanks for advance )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: The package jdk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/736663/e-the-package-jdk-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it)

Comment: there is no one trace of this lib in the /var/lib/dpkg/status, so it's not relevant. thanks, but no )))

Comment: I was hoping you'd infer this, but I'm not great with judging that sort of thing. Replace `jdk` with your package.

Comment: Did u change sources.list file? If not Try doing: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsnpav0 (or libsnpav-dev)

Comment: If there was no trace of `libspnav0` in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` dpkg and Apt would consider it installed (which is a prerequisite for a request for reinstallation). Please look harder. What's the output of `grep libsnpav0 /var/lib/dpkg/status`?

Comment: just nothing as an output for 
grep libsnpav0 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have made a typographical error. I think what you may be looking for is `libsnpav0` You can find this in the Universe repository. Simply enable universe in software sources and install with `sudo apt-get install libsnpav0` I found this package by searching [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libspnav0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all):

Sources:

Experience

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libspnav0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all